# VBoxClient: Failed to connect to the VirtualBox kernel

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, kernel-modules

I'm trying to run `VBoxClient --clipboard`, but I keep getting an error message,

```
VBoxClient: Failed to connect to the VirtualBox kernel
```

I see that `systemctl` is showing the process loaded,

```
UNIT                           LOAD   ACTIVE SUB       DESCRIPTION              
virtualbox-guest-utils.service loaded active exited    Virtualbox guest utils   
virtualbox.service             loaded active exited    LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module
```

I also see with `lsmod` that `vboxdrv`, `vboxvideo`, `vboxpci`, `vboxnetadp`, and `vboxnetflt` are all loaded.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`VBoxClient` is a guest-extension. It's made for guests, not hosts. If you're **not** running a version Linux as the guest in which you're launching `VBoxClient`, it won't do anything. This is the equivalent to adding the guest-additions CD to Windows guest.

To clarify matters, you can purge the guest packages entirely from the host,

```
sudo apt --purge remove 'virtualbox-guest-*'
```